# ASP.NET: Pass register ID through 'Update' button

Tags: asp.net-core, http-post

I'm constructing this view where the user can edit multiple item and save one at the time with the 'Update' button.

[image: Update Multiple Items]

**Problem:** I have trouble making the 'Update' button work. Here is the post method:

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Test")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> TestPost(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var machinetoUpdate = await _context.Machines
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == id);
        if (await TryUpdateModelAsync(
            machinetoUpdate,
            "",
            s => s.MchName, s => s.StoreID, s => s.PUnit, s => s.Status))
        {
            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. " +
                    "Try again, and if the problem persists, " +
                    "see your system administrator.");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Test");
        }
        return View(machinetoUpdate);
    }
```

I have the problem in this line. The ActionResult is expecting the 'id' of the Machine been updated

```
public async Task<IActionResult> TestPost(int? id)
```

but since I'm not updating a single item I suppose I could send the 'id' with the Update button onclick? At this moment the button is doing nothing.

This is the code for each button:

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input id="@item.Id" type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

How can I make this work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to send the id with the request. You can use JavaScript for this or use a separate form per row with a different destination url set. The id can be part of the route like /123 or a query string like ?123 or a hidden form field.

Comment: Hello ssmith, thanks for the reply. I'm the Jon Snow of JS so I'll try to skip that. The second option, use a separate form per row means I would have to re-do the view and use forms instead of the table? In case 'yes', could you give me an example of what it would look like to pass the 'ID' thru a hidden form field? Thanks!

Comment: HTML forms are invisible so they are a separate concept from tables. You would simply wrap each set of inputs (and their div elements etc) inside a <form>...</form> tag. Point each form to an id specific location using its action attribute: action="/endpoint/1".

Comment: For hidden form your would just add <input type="hidden" name="id" value="123" /> but only one of these per form.